# tensorflow summary ops can assign to gpu

Tags: tensorflow

Here is part of my code.

```
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    global_step = tf.get_variable(
        'global_step',
        [],
        initializer = tf.constant_initializer(0),
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path,graph=tf.get_default_graph())

    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        tf.summary.scalar('learning_rate', INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE)
        summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

when I run it. I will get following error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device for operation 'learning_rate': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no
>    supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
>            [[Node: learning_rate = ScalarSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/device:GPU:0"](learning_rate/tags, learning_rate/values)]]

if I move these 2 ops into tf.device("/cpu:0") device scope, It will work.

```
            tf.summary.scalar('learning_rate', INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE)
        summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

I google it. there are many suggestiones about using "allow_soft_placement=True". But I think this solution is basically change device scope automatically. So my question is:
why these 2 ops can not assign to gpu? Is there any documents I can look at to figure out what ops can or cannot assign to gpu? 
any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign a summary operation to a GPU because is meaningless.

In short, a GPU executes parallel operations. A summary is nothing but a file in which you append new lines every time you write on it. It's a sequential operation that has nothing in common with the operation that GPUs are capable to do.

Comment: The summary operation does not write the summary file, that task is for a `SummaryWriter`. The summary op only gathers the data that should be written to a summary file and thus, in principle, could very well be executed on a GPU (I agree that there is probably no point in doing that, but hey, someone might have a reason I can't think of).

Comment: Conceptually it's the same. You're defining a summary that logs a variable value. A value *can't* change in parallel: multiple operations can cooperate to compute the value of that variable, but and the end of the operation the value is fixed. Otherwise, there's a race condition. The value to log, thus, can be gathered by the summary only when it has a definite value. If this operation is executed in parallel we could potentially log for the same time step more than one value, that's no sense

Comment: The variable produced can be an array of values, tough. And said values might be computed in parallel. But even if the value produced at the end is one (e.g. the average of the activations of a layer), there might be parallellism exploitable in the computation of that single variable (for the average example, it is possible to write a parallel averaging algorithm that runs on a GPU). The result value can, then, be transferred to CPU for the SummaryWriter to store on disk.

Comment: so, Basically, Tensorflow will check the 'compatibility' between ops and device, if the allow_soft_placement is on, then It will do some ajustment, if it is off, then raise an exception? Then standard of compatibility is that if the ops can be run in paralle (basically, matrix operation)?

Comment: Yes. There's the concept of CUDA kernel that consists of a function that can be executed in parallel on the GPU. They kept the same concept and added the possibility of "register" a kernel to a particular device. Operations that can't be executed in parallel or that have no CUDA implementation (for whatever reason) are registered only on the CPU register. Operations (kernels) that can be executed on both are registered on the GPU register and the CPU register. When you try to place an operation on a device, the register associated with that device is consulted.

Answer (score 1):

Your error says it all:

> Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' **because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available**.

That operation (in the tensorflow version you're using) has no GPU implementation and thus must be sent to a CPU device.